# how to get each entity's id when batch insert using mybatis

Tags: java, insert, entity, mybatis

it is know that when we save an entity using `mybatis`,we can use the `keyProperty` and `useGeneratedKeys` attribute to get the entity's id.but how I can get each entity's id when I batch insert entities using just like below:

```
<insert id="inserts" keyProperty="id" useGeneratedKeys="true">
        insert into t_ext_wk_agent (agent_code,agent_name,agent_type,icon,agent_url_state,description,target,
        state,create_time,modify_time)
        values
        <foreach collection="list" separator="," item="item">
            (#{item.agentCode},#{item.agentName},#{item.agentType},#{item.icon},#{item.agentUrlState},#{item.description},
            #{item.target},#{item.state},#{item.createTime},#{item.modifyTime})
        </foreach> 
    </insert>
```

Answer (score 0):

I have just posted a related [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32649759/using-foreach-to-do-batch-insert-with-mybatis/40608353#40608353).

Just execute a simple Insert statement in a Java Foreach loop instead of iterating over collection in Mybatis XML. The most important thing is the session Executor type (REUSE or BATCH). You then come back to the simple *insert / get generated key* case